# Sort files in specific folder with ranger

Tags: ranger

I would like to sort the files in my Screenshots folder by date, so I added the following to my rc.conf:

```
setlocal PATH=~/Screenshots sort mtime
setlocal PATH=~/Screenshots sort_reverse False
```

But it does not seem to work. Did I make a syntax error?

Thanks

Comment: Which distribution, version and kernel version are you running?

Answer (score 10):

While not an edit to rc.conf, these key bindings should help. "os" sorts by size first. Pressing "o" will bring up a list of different options. This resource helped me find the answers: http://dquinton.github.io/debian-install/files/ranger-keybinds_quinton.pdf.

Answer (score 8):

The `path` variable must be in lowercase, not in uppercase.

```
setlocal path=~/Screenshots sort mtime
setlocal path=~/Screenshots sort_reverse False
```

(tested on ranger-stable 1.8.1)

See the [default rc.conf file](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/blob/master/ranger/config/rc.conf).